Нужно ли ставить тире в предложении "Он - симпатичный"
Здравствуйте? Подскажите, нужно ли ставить тире в данном предложении: "Он - симпатичный"?
Контекст такой: "Рекомендую вам отель "Прованс". Он - симпатичный"

✦ В подавляющем большинстве случаев тире в такой конструкции не нужно:
Рекомендую вам отель "Прованс". Он симпатичный.

10. Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным (в том числе местоименным) или предложно-именным сочетанием, тире перед сказуемым обычно не ставится: Погода несносная, дорога скверная, ямщик упрямый... (П.)...
Тире перед сказуемым-прилагательным ставится:
1) при логическом или интонационном членении предложения: Зрачки — кошачьи, длинные (Ш.); Высота возле разбросанных домиков хутора — командная
(Каз.)...

• Если же нужно выделить подлежащее он паузой (например, при выборе из нескольких отелей), то постановка авторского знака (интонационного тире) вполне возможна.
Вот, например, в таком диалоге:
— Я была уже в двух отелях! Везде — стандартные коробки, обшарпанные стены!
— Рекомендую вам отель "Прованс". Он — симпатичный.
• Можно ли использовать прилагательное симпатичный по отношению к зданию?
Думаю, что да.
Из толкового словаря Дмитриева:
симпатичный
3. Симпатичным называют красиво сделанный предмет.
Симпатичный брелок, халат. | Мы остановились у симпатичного домика с резными наличниками.
Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым (Розенталь)

В данном случае лучше выбрать вариант с тире:
Рекомендую вам отель "Прованс". Он — симпатичный.
РЕШЕНИЕ
Тире интонационное: при такой грамматике и при таком контексте  ставится при логическом  подчеркивании подлежащего ударением. Тогда предложение делится паузой на две части, а на письме ставится тире. Другое произношение выглядит неестественным, так как фраза очень короткая по сравнению с предыдущим предложением.
Сравним: Рекомендую вам отель "Прованс". Он довольно симпатИчный.  Здесь уже лучше подходит произношение без паузы, тире не ставится.
Также:  Рекомендую вам отель "ПровАнс", он симпатИчный.  В составе сложного предложения интонация другая, поэтому нет тире; фраза выглядит законченной.
ОБОСНОВАНИЕ
Оба варианта разрешены правилами Розенталя:
  10. Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным (в том числе 
  местоименным) или предложно-именным сочетанием, тире перед 
  сказуемым обычно не ставится: Погода несносная, дорога 
  скверная, ямщик упрямый… (П.); Земля велика и прекрасна 
  (Ч.); Вишнёвый сад мой! (Ч.); Небо без единого облачка; 
  Люди здесь необыкновенной доброты.

Тире перед сказуемым-прилагательным ставится:
 1) при логическом или интонационном членении 
 предложения: Зрачки — кошачьи, длинные (Ш.); Высота возле 
 разбросанных домиков хутора — командная (Каз.);

В этих примерах ясно видно, что ударением выделено подлежащее: ЗрачкИ — кошачьи, длинные.
ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ
Знаки препинания отражают стиль текста — он должен легко читаться. Не поставишь нужный  знак (тире в данном случае) — и при чтении возникает заминка, нет фонетического благозвучия. Хорошие питатели  это хорошо чувствуют. Поэтому применять правила Розенталя надо разумно, а не по общим стандартам. Каждый знак подходит к конкретному авторскому  тексту, не стоит забывать об этом.
Просто надо прочитать предложение в контексте так, как вы его слышите и выбрать один из альтернативных знаков (тире при наличии паузы или его отсутствие без паузы). В русской пунктуации много альтернативных вариантов, разрешенных правилами, и выбор здесь всегда необходим. Я бы сказала, что знание пунктуации — это прежде всего умение решать альтернативные задачи.
Этот примечание я предлагаю учитывать всем участникам и гостям форума. Как это ни банально звучит, но знаки надо "слышать". Интуитивно мы читаем текст правильно, даже без учета правил.
